# same linkedlist code different behavior between groovy and java, why

Tags: java, groovy

I am using `linkedlist` as a stack in groovy

as doc says, `pop()` take elm from the first

```
Stack Method  Equivalent Deque Method  
push(e)       addFirst(e) 
pop()         removeFirst()
```

so a `linkedlist` [1,2,3] should pop() 1 2 3

and it does in Java, but does NOT in groovy. WHY?

test below

`A.java`

```
import java.util.*;

public class A{


    public static void main(String[] args){

        String[] x = "1/2/3/".split("/");
        LinkedList <String> stack = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList(x));
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
    }
}
```

compile and run

```
$ javac A.java
$ java A
1
```

runing in groovy

```
$ ln -s A.java A.groovy
$ groovy A.groovy
3
```

here is my java and groovy version

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_51-b11-457-11M4509)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.51-b01-457, mixed mode)

$ groovy -version
Groovy Version: 2.1.5 JVM: 1.6.0_51 Vendor: Apple Inc. OS: Mac OS X
```

Comment: maybe you should output the list state prior to pop.

Comment: @BevynQ seems ok groovy:000> [1,2,3] as LinkedList
===> [1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a "feature" of groovy. [Default Groovy Methods](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html) are described as `This class defines new groovy methods which appear on normal JDK classes inside the Groovy environment.`

One of the methods that `DefaultGroovyMethods` provides is [pop()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#pop(java.util.List)), which is described as: `Removes the last item from the List.` So it appears that Groovy is weaving in a different implementation of `pop()` which is conflicting with what `LinkedList` provides you by default.

[A bug report](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4181) filed against GDM a few years ago describes it best, and provides some additional commentary: `LinkedList seems to implement List and a pop/push method, thus the classes method should not be shadowed by a DGM method. Only if we had a LinkedList#pop/push method in DGM, it should be different.`